# "<<" operator in java

Tags: java, operators

Fallowing statement is from Character class of java:

```
(1 << Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR)) >> type
```

`PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR` is a byte and `type` is an integer.

The operators in this sentence, what do they do? how and where I can use those operators?

Here is the oracles [java.lang.Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) doc. Nearly all the methods in the class uses those operators.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?  I don't see it in the current API documents.

Comment: Can you post a reference to the doc to which you refer?

Comment: Its almost everywere in the class java.lang.Character, Character.isDefined(),Character.isLetter()...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are bit-shift operators. `<<` shifts the bits "left" (towards the most-significant bit), and vice-versa for `>>`. Shifting left or right by *n* bits is pretty much the same as multiplying or dividing, respectively, by 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

See @axtavt's comment for an explanation of how these operators are being used in this context.

Comment: It works as a highly optimized multiple comparison. Full expression looks like `((((1 << Character.LINE_SEPARATOR) | (1 << Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR)) >> type) & 1) != 0`, it returns `true` if `type` matches one of the constants. Also the first part of expression is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3):

These are the [bitwise shift](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operators.

If you *left shift* the following byte:

```
00000001
```

you would get:

```
00000010
```

I.e. the pattern has "shifted" to the left and zeros fill in on the right. So if you apply the right shift operator `>>` on that result, you'll get the original byte again.

You'll notice that the decimal values of these numbers are 1 and 2. If you shift left once again you'll get:

```
00000100 = 4
```

So you see that shifting to the left multiplies the number by two (given that it doesn't overflow), while right shifting divides by two. This happens very efficiently in most computers. So that's one example of how you might use these operators in a practical way.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise operators: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the left shift operator: It shifts the binary number stored in the computer left. For example, 9 in binary is 1001. `9 << 2` makes 100100 in binary (36), because it shifts it left and adds 0s at the end. `1 << n` is the same thing as `Math.pow(2, n)` except it is way faster and better in general, as well as returning `int`, not `double`.

`>>` is right shift. It shifts it right, and discards empty bits. 13 is 1101 in binary, so `13 >> 1` is 110 in binary, or 6 normally.

Answer (score 1):

It works as a highly optimized multiple comparison. The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

for more detail,You can visit below link .
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html